# External links in Facbook don't work in WKWebView. Any idea how to resolve this?

Tags: ios, swift

Facebook has external links to all sorts of sites. These can be opened successfully in Safari on `iOS` and even using `UISafariViewController`.
However in a `WKWebView` these links are not clickable, as if there is no link, just the text.

Anybody experienced something similar or knows how to resolve this?

Other web-sites opening external links are not a problem. It seems to be a Facebook specific issue. Almost as if Facebook is actively preventing this.
I found a difference in the User Agent of Safari and of `WKWebView`, maybe Facebook is making use of this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem , with one of the pages in WkWebview

Basically when the link on this page is clicked , it opens a new page and it works very well with ***Mobile safari*** and ***SFSafariViewController*** but not with the *WkWebview*

WKWebView does not open any links which have **target="_blank"** i.e 'Open in new Window'

Here is what I did

Implement *WKNavigationDelegate* on current view controller

```
@interface ViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate>
{

}
```

Assign navigation delegate to current view controller

```
WKWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
```

and implement the navigation delegate like below ( This lets target _blank links to be opened on current window )

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    BOOL shouldLoad = [self shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationAction.request];

    if (shouldLoad && navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
        [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    }
    decisionHandler(shouldLoad ? WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow : WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration of this solution.
I thought I have this in place, but will double check when I have access to my machine again.
What are the symptoms if this is not in place, according to your experience?

Comment: Basically when you click on any link on a webpage that takes you to new page rather opening it on top of that will seem like page's links are not working

Comment: Exactly my sympthom. Was double checking my implementation for this and got it to work, thanks a lot for your help.